# AS3: mailto: with special characters in Outlook

Tags: actionscript-3, encoding, outlook, mailto

I want to send an email with special characters (like cyrillic) from a swf. To make sure it will be displayed correctly in the mail client, I use

```
encodeURI()
```

It works fine in Apple Mail, but in Outlook I only see gibberish. I learned that Outlook uses iso-8859-1 for "mailto:"-mails (at least by default). So two questions arise:

1. is there a way to encode the mailto: string in iso-8859-1?
2. would this break the correct display of characters in other mail clients?

I am sure that the second question can not have a definitive answer, nevertheless I would be thankful for any advise.

EDIT: unfortunately, html email and php is not an option for me.

Comment: Is it the content or the email address that contains special characters ? Cause if it's the email address, it's just wrong ! email addresses aren't supposed to have special characters..

Comment: No, it is the content. I need at least the body to display special characters.

Comment: Then just html encode your special characters and send the email as html ?

Comment: Sorry no, you cannot send html mails with mailto.

Comment: The question is vague. What are you trying to do? (a) In an swf, you want a 'Email Me at me@myself.com' button for the user to write an email which will go to you or (b) In an swf, create an email and send it to someone?

Comment: Yes, in a swf I am displaying a button which, when clicked, calls "navigateToURL()" with an URLRequest with "mailto:(...)" The mailto-String contains no recipient adress, but a subject and a body. So the user's email client will open with a precomposed mail. The problem is that in Outlook, characters like cyrillic characters are displayed wrong. The problem does not occur in Apple Mail.

Answer (score -2):

You are using the wrong tech my friend. Just post your email data to some php script and use php to send a html email.

Comment: You are right, under normal circumstances this would be my route. But in this case this is not possible for legal reasons. ("not possible" <- not wanted by the marketing people because of additional opt-ins from the user-)